# Xcode iOS Notability "zoom box"

Tags: ios, xcode, view

Notability and other note taking apps have this 'zoom box' feature where you can draw in the magnified box at the bottom. Users can also drag the box at the top to change what they want magnified at the bottom. I have tried literally everything I can think of to add this feature in my app. I have added the same document in two views but then I run into many memory issues, I've duplicated the file but again memory issues. Does anyone know a simple way to do this? Is there anyway I can just have a view that is a magnification of another view?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Create a new Cocoa Touch Class (optionally name it MagnifyView) and set it as a subclass of UIView
Add the following code in your class:

```
var viewToMagnify: UIView!
var touchPoint: CGPoint!

override init(frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit()
{
    // Set border color, border width and corner radius of the magnify view
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 3
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

func setTouchPoint(pt: CGPoint)
{
    touchPoint = pt
    self.center = CGPoint(x: pt.x, y: pt.y - 100)
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context!.translateBy(x: 1 * (self.frame.size.width * 0.5), y: 1 * (self.frame.size.height * 0.5))
    context!.scaleBy(x: 1.5, y: 1.5) // 1.5 is the zoom scale
    context!.translateBy(x: -1 * (touchPoint.x), y: -1 * (touchPoint.y))
    self.viewToMagnify.layer.render(in: context!)
}
```

To use it, implement touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnd functions in View Controller which you want to have the magnifying effect.

Here is how:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let point = touches.first?.location(in: self.view)
    if magnifyView == nil
    {
        magnifyView = MagnifyView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        magnifyView.viewToMagnify = self.view
        magnifyView.setTouchPoint(pt: point!)
        self.view.addSubview(magnifyView)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if magnifyView != nil
    {
        magnifyView.removeFromSuperview()
        magnifyView = nil
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let point = touches.first?.location(in: self.view)
    magnifyView.setTouchPoint(pt: point!)
    magnifyView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

original source [here](https://tutsline.wordpress.com/2017/08/14/how-to-create-a-magnifier-effect-in-swift-3-ios/)

Comment: this is the main idea behind it i recommend reading the source, to give you and idea and then you customize it as you need

Comment: and you can use a pod for that to save some work if u able to , i recommend this one https://cocoapods.org/pods/iOS-MagnifyingGlass

Comment: Thank you so replying! Thank you! When I try this on PDFkit it's 'blurry' on the magnifying view. Any thoughts?

Comment: this could be anything, might be the document it self try different one if so, try to play with the aspect ratio of the Zoom box, please upvote my answer if it was helpful thank you @JimBak

Comment: the frame rate is very low using PDF Kit... Any ideas?

Comment: This is another question and unfortunately I don’t know

Comment: +1 for a good answer. @JimBak To add to this, if you are interested in doing this ONLY for PDF files, (you mentioned pdf kit), use [Core Graphic's PDF APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF109). Specifically check `CGContextDrawPDFPage`. Use this to draw pdf content instead of just redrawing magnified version of the view in your magnification `CGContext`. This should help with the 'blurry' magnification because pdf drawing scalable (vector).